# memory content not erased after deleting my pointer (on a simple example)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Here is a simple of example of a question I have:
I create a pointer of integer (value 5), I print the pointer (hence the address) of the memory case it points to, as well as its content (5).

Then I delete that pointer, which is supposed to delete the content in the memory case that has the address of the pointer.
But then when I print **a** and its content, as expected the address still exists. Nevertheless the content remains the same (5) as if **a** was not deleted... 
could you explain me? :-)

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int * a = new int(5);
    std::cout<< a << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "--------" << std::endl;
    delete a;
    std::cout<< a << std::endl;
    std::cout<< *a << std::endl;

    // end of my main
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
0x7fff28403a90
--------  
0x7fff28403a90
5
```

Comment: _"Then I delete that pointer, which is supposed to delete the content in the memory case that has the address of the pointer."_ Where did you hear that?

Comment: This famous Q&A is not a direct duplicate but is the perfect answer for just the same reason. I'm therefore biting the bullet and picking it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may or may not print the same value after delete operation. So simply what you are observing is an undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see, when it frees the memory it does not replace the content by something else but in fact it keeps the content, but someone can write into that address anytime.

Comment: undefined behavior does not mean it should crash;   What it means you will get non-deterministic result.